# Insert Standard JSON into DynamoDB aws-sdk js v3

Tags: json, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js-v3

I am trying to register `Standard JSON` in `DynamoDB` using [aws-sdk version 3 for JS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/classes/dynamodb.html#putitem) in the **thumbnail** field.

In version 2 it was allowed using the `put` method, in the version 3 now are commands but I not see an equivalent command.

**My code:**

```
const { DynamoDBClient, PutItemCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb');

const DynamoDBDocClient = new DynamoDBClient({ region: "us-east-1"});
const item = {
    PK: "My_pk",
    SK: "My_sk",
    username: "My_username",
    thumbnail: {
        id: "My_id",
        width: "My_width",
        height: "My_height"
    }
}

const params = {
    Item: item,
    TableName: "My_table"
};

await DynamoDBDocClient.send(new PutItemCommand(params));
```

**The error:**

```
ERROR   TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at Object.visit (/var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist/cjs/models/models_0.js:1101:40)
at serializeAws_json1_0AttributeValue (/var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist/cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:4612:38)
at /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist/cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:5514:20
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
```

I can only register the item its use `marshall` (from `@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb`) but it registers as `DynamoDB JSON`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In v3 you have to use the [@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/tree/main/lib/lib-dynamodb) library to get similar functionality to the `DynamoDB.DocumentClient` in the old SDK. It works a bit differently, but it should do what you want.